# Communication PC <-> Android Device

Tags: android

I would like to create a program which communicates between PC and an Android mobile connected to USB via tcp/ip. Is this possible? How can I get the IP-address to a connected mobile from PC or the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, see for example [this app](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/android-media-center-remote-control/). As to how they do it I don't know.

Comment: gmote seems to connect thru wifi, right? I want to connect thru an usb cable

Nicholas